# QtQuick not found (Lubuntu)

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, qt, qml, qt5

On a fresh Lubuntu 13.04 installation, I installed Qt5 from the official ubuntu repositories. But this installation of Qt5 can't find the QtQuick module. What am I missing?

```
qmlscene test.qml
```

test.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
}
```

Output:

> file:///home/.../test.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed

I already double-checked that the following relevant packages are installed:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep libqt5
libqt53d5:amd64                 install
libqt5clucene5:amd64                install
libqt5concurrent5:amd64             install
libqt5core5:amd64               install
libqt5dbus5:amd64               install
libqt5declarative5:amd64            install
libqt5designer5:amd64               install
libqt5designercomponents5:amd64         install
libqt5gui5:amd64                install
libqt5help5:amd64               install
libqt5location5:amd64               install
libqt5network5:amd64                install
libqt5opengl5:amd64             install
libqt5opengl5-dev               install
libqt5printsupport5:amd64           install
libqt5qml5:amd64                install
libqt5quick5:amd64              install
libqt5quickparticles5:amd64         install
libqt5quicktest5:amd64              install
libqt5script5:amd64             install
libqt5sensors5:amd64                install
libqt5sql5:amd64                install
libqt5sql5-mysql:amd64              install
libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64             install
libqt5svg5:amd64                install
libqt5test5:amd64               install
libqt5v8-5:amd64                install
libqt5webkit5:amd64             install
libqt5widgets5:amd64                install
libqt5xml5:amd64                install
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin` installed. If you just install `ubuntu-sdk` it will install pretty much everything you need.